# Split PDF files when it detects a QR code

Tags: pdf, batch-processing

My company is scanning high volumes of documents which the scanner converts them into searchable PDF's. These are outputted to a directory on a server for processing.

My problem is that a user must scan the documents 1 batch at a time. Each batch has a front page with a QR code. I would like the users to be able to scan multiple batches at a single time but this combines them into a single PDF. What then happens is that when they are processed on the server it only sees the first page which has the QR code and is treated as a single file.

Does anyone know of any software options where it can look at the PDF file and splits it into multiple files when it comes across a QR code?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is the QR code on an active page, or on its own page? If on its own page, I could imagine a custom page size, which could be detected in Acrobat, using Acrobat JavaScript.

Comment: QR code is on it's own page

Comment: In this case, make the page with the QR code a specific size, different from the others. You then can create a script which loops through the pages and creates a list of the pages with the QR code page size. This list can then be used as input into the extractPages() function to break up the document into documents beginning with a QR code page and containing all the pages until the next QR code page (or the end of the document).